# Are ProtocolBuffers/Thrift suitable for communication and messaging between data centers?

Tags: protocols, soa, thrift

We currently have data centers in multiple geographic regions each hosting different applications and services that need to communicate with each other. Currently we are using http for communications and want to explore other protocols for performance reasons. Can one use ProtocolBuffers or Thrift for traffic between geographic regions over tcp/ip? If so does the latency kill any performance gains ProtocolBuffers or Thrift would provide? Are there other options that are suitable?

Comment: I can't speak for your specific scenario, but any work I've done with large scale geographic transfers has led me to the conclusion that the protocol is a very minor component. The biggest speedup is at the application level and analyzing what data is being sent that's being repeated and putting an end to that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Apache Thrift, but I think you've misunderstood the purpose of Protocol Buffers.  Protocol Buffers is a data serialization format, much like JSON or XML; it doesn't specify or implement any particular network transport (you could put it over TCP, or UDP, or save it to disk or even transport it over HTTP if you wanted to).  Even Protocol Buffers' [services feature](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#services) just generates the interface and stub implementation for you; it's up to the developer to implement a way to send messages back and forth.

See the [Protocol Buffers Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) to learn more about what Protocol Buffers actually is and how it can benefit you.  In your case (replacing an HTTP-based protocol), Protocol Buffers can probably reduce some of the size overhead inherent in the XML or JSON that you're probably sending now, since it's not wasting bytes on human-readability.